# I want to update a page, but i use special characters like ç/ã/á

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

It is correctly printing in UTF-8_encode(), but after i update it , cause i have a button to update the database, it prints with some stupid characters...
I have it on the database in a table, and when i list it on a page and then change something and update it to the database it print with stupid characters
Code where i update:

```
 <?php
if (!isset($_SESSION["auth"])) {
header('Location: index.php?backUrl='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
exit();
}
$host="localhost"; // Nome do host onde esta o banco de dados. Padrão ‘localhost’ 
$usuario="root"; // Usuário do Mysql. Padrão ‘root
$senha=""; // Senha do Mysql  
$db ="teste"; // Nome da Database 


  ?>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<h2 align="center" style="color:white; font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:20px;">Alteração de Orgãos</h2>
  <form action="" method="POST" name="alt" id="alt" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="box">
            <label>
              <textarea rows="20" cols="100" id="texto" name="texto"><?php 


$mysqli = mysqli_connect("$host", "$usuario", "$senha")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($mysqli,$db)or die("cannot select DB");
                        $query2 = "Select * from teste";
              $stat=$mysqli->query($query2);
              if($stat->num_rows>0)
                                {             
                                    while ($row = $stat->fetch_assoc()) {
                  echo utf8_encode($row["texto"]);
                }
              } else
              {
                echo utf8_encode("Não existe nada na página");
              }
                      ?></textarea>
            </label>

        <label >
            <input align="center" type="submit" value="Alterar" name="alterar_btn" id="alterar_btn" class="entrar">   
  </label>


        </div>
        </form>
        <?php 
$a1=$b1=$c1=$d1='';

//Alterar
if(isset($_POST['texto']))
{
  if(isset($_POST['alterar_btn']))
  {
    $query="update teste set texto=? where titulo='orgaos'";
   $stat = $mysqli->prepare($query);
   $stat->bind_param('s',$_POST['texto']);

 if ($stat->execute() && $stat->affected_rows>0){
      echo "<div><strong>Foi alterado um Orgão!</strong></div>";
 }
 else{
      echo "<div><strong>Nao foi alterado!</strong></div>";
 }
 $stat->close();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: your column COLLATE type should be utf_general_ci

Comment: @devpro im using PHPMYADMIN and it doens't appear that, only utf16_general

Comment: i mean utf8_general_ci in COLLATION

Comment: i changed it, and when i update,with the button it keeps changing the ó's to À

Comment: you also need to use html entities special char

Comment: now it changes the letters to Í